# Why is MongoDB creating indexes for fields that don't exist within that schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, indexing

TL;DR: I am having trouble with my mongo database seemingly creating indexes for my boards collection from fields from my users collection which is causing E11000 errors when I try to create a new board.

I am building a kanban board (like Jira) and have board, task and user collections (entity relationship diagram :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddEi8.jpg). All of the collections work fine following a .dropIndexes(). However, when I have been working with tasks via the UI on one board, when I try to create another board I get this E11000 error:

```
{ MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: kanban.boards.$username_1  dup key: { : null }
    at Function.create (/home/ubuntu/workspace/kanban v1.0/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:43:12)
    at toError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/kanban v1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:149:22)
    at coll.s.topology.insert (/home/ubuntu/workspace/kanban v1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/collection_ops.js:859:39)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/kanban v1.0/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:532:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  driver: true,
  name: 'MongoError',
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  errmsg: 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: kanban.boards.$username_1  dup key: { : null }' }
```

This appears to be because of a null value in the username field in the board schema but there is no such field in this model as can be seen below:

```
// Board Schema

// Config
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");


// Create Board Schema

var BoardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", unique: true, sparse: true},
    todo: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Task"}],
    inProgress: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Task"}],
    testing: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Task"}],
    completed: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Task"}]
});


// Validation
BoardSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);


// Export Model
module.exports = mongoose.model("Board", BoardSchema);
```

Here is an example board in the db:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c65767c8977670a2366ffe5"), 
"todo" : [ ObjectId("5c657a1e451bc80ac315ef35"), ObjectId("5c657a4a451bc80ac315ef37"), ObjectId("5c657a76451bc80ac315ef39") ], 
"inProgress" : [ ObjectId("5c6579e1451bc80ac315ef31"), ObjectId("5c657a03451bc80ac315ef33"), ObjectId("5c657a3a451bc80ac315ef36"), ObjectId("5c657a8a451bc80ac315ef3a") ], 
"testing" : [ ObjectId("5c657a9a451bc80ac315ef3b") ], 
"completed" : [ ObjectId("5c657a60451bc80ac315ef38"), ObjectId("5c65bb8f6f5b731aec27b4a7"), ObjectId("5c65bba06f5b731aec27b4a8"), ObjectId("5c657a11451bc80ac315ef34") ], 
"user" : ObjectId("5c65767b8977670a2366ffe4"), 
"__v" : 51 }
```

For some reason, I think a username index has been created by the database for the boards schema. The indexes for the boards collection are below:

```
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "kanban.boards"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "user" : 1
                },
                "name" : "user_1",
                "ns" : "kanban.boards",
                "background" : true
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "unique" : true,
                "key" : {
                        "username" : 1
                },
                "name" : "username_1",
                "ns" : "kanban.boards",
                "background" : true
        }
]
```

For completeness, here is the user schema:

```
// User Schema

// Config

var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    uniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator"),
    passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");


// Create User Schema

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: String
});


// Validation and Hash/Salt PW
UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, {message: "A user is already registered with that {PATH}."});
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);


// Export Model
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

The code causing the error is in the signup route, part of which is shown below:

```
// create new board for user
        var newBoard = {
            user: user._id,
            todo: [],
            inProgress: [],
            testing: [],
            review: [],
            completed: [],
        };


        Board.create(newBoard, function(err, board) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                req.flash("error", "Uh oh! Something went wrong.");
                return res.redirect("/");
            }

            // authenticate user
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
                req.flash("success", "Welcome to your Kanban board, " + user.username + ".");
                return res.redirect("/board");
            });

        });
```

I don't understand why this index is being created (or indeed if this is what is causing the E11000 errors but I'm pretty sure it is). Apologies for the spam of code, I am quite inexperienced with using mongo and so don't know what is relevant and what is not. I have built mongo databases with multiple collections before but not with a link collection as I have here so I can't work out what is going wrong. Please let me know if I have missed anything that is useful or important. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried manually deleting the index, and seeing if it gets recreated automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was plugging passport-local-mongoose into the board schema when that should only be on the user schema.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the issue, but you should remove the `unique: true` and `sparse: true` from the BoardSchema.user parameter. Since you declare those in the UserSchema, you shouldn't also need them in the BoardSchema.

EDIT: You might also have to manually delete the index after completing this first step.

Comment: I added these parameters after the issue first appeared to try to fix it but I've removed them again and dropped the database. So far the issue is fixed but I'll keep an eye on it. Thanks.

Comment: The username index has returned after stopping the db and node server and restarting it all 12 hours later.